# MSSQL for Node: How to use LIKE with an input parameter in the query?

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, node.js, npm

I didn't know how to ask the question and I couldn't find a solution. I am using the mssql NPM package. The documentation has nothing on this.

I'd like to get this to work:

```
SELECT product_price
FROM products
WHERE product_name LIKE '%SEARCH_CRITERIA%'         -- note the '%%' part
```

with the **mssql** npm package for node:

```
var query = `
    SELECT product_price
    FROM products
    WHERE product_name LIKE @input_parameter
`

new sql.ConnectionPool(db).connect().then(pool => {
    return pool.request()
    .input('input_parameter', criteria)           // How do I make LIKE work?
    .query(query)
}).then(result => {
    res.send(result)
}).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({ message: "${err}"})
    sql.close();
});
```

Using `=` in the query works fine, but I need the `LIKE` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried prefixing and suffixing the contents of `criteria` with the `%`?

e.g.

```
new sql.ConnectionPool(db).connect().then(pool => {
return pool.request()
.input('input_parameter', '%'+criteria+'%')
.query(query)
}).then(result =>
   ...etc
```

Comment: Damn... How did I miss that. Code fatigue I guess. Thank you.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Comment: But cant we have namedParameters this looks more welcome for injection attack